# Create inherited Class from BaseClass

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to instantiate an inherited class from a Base class.

I have tried with this code:

```
public class BasicClass
{
    private static BasicClass instance;
    private BasicClass() { }

    public static BasicClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                var dataType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
                instance = (BasicClass)Activator.CreateInstance(dataType);
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}



public class MyClass1 : BasicClass
{

}

public class MyClass2 : BasicClass
{

}
```

And then call it :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var o = MyClass2.Instance;

        Text = o.GetType().Name;
    }
}
```

I my small demo I've used a WinForm application but that's just for testing.

My problem is that I get an instance of `BasicClass` not `MyClass2` Can I some how get `MyClass2`

Comment: Unfortunately, in .NET, static members are not seen as "belonging to" any other class than the one they are declared on. Hence, the getter of your `Instance` property cannot possibly have any knowledge about the class you actually used to invoke it.

Comment: Do you have an other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I some how get `MyClass2`?

No, at least not with the approach that you took. `GetCurrentMethod()` will not get you the method in the caller, it will give you the method that implements the getter property.

Moreover, consider this declaration:

```
private static BasicClass instance;
```

There's only one `instance` in your program, no matter how many subclasses you create. The problem is that if `MyClass2` creates an instance and stores it in `BasicClass.instance`, there's no place for `MyClass1`'s instance to go.

One approach that you could take would be using a dictionary that maps subtypes to instances, and a generic method for accessing them, like this:

```
private static IDictionary<Type,BasicClass> instances = new Dictionary<Type,BasicClass>();
...
public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : BasicClass {
    BasicClass res;
    if (!instances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out res)) {
        res = (BasicClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        instances.Add(typeof(T), res);
    }
    return (T)res;
}
...
var o = MyClass2.GetInstance<MyClass2>();
```

Comment: Ok ok ... Then lets say that it wasn't a singleton. Could it then be done?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt Take a look at the edit, this should fix at least the immediate problem that you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is: [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern cannot be inherited. This is because static fields (Instance, for ex.) are declared in special so-called `Type Object`? which in your case is `BaseType` and so they no nothing about their children
What do you want to achieve?

You can implement a wrapper like this:

```
public class Singleton<T>
        where T:class, new()
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<T> _instance = new Lazy<T>(()=>new T()); 

        public static T Instance
        {
            get { return _instance.Value; }
        }
    }
```

See answer below, which provides cool implementation of Singleton wrapper

Answer (score 2):

You can create a templated base class:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{      
  private static readonly Lazy<T> instance = new Lazy<T>(() => CreateInstance());   

  public static T Instance { get { return instance.Value; } }

  private static T CreateInstance()
  {
    return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), true) as T;
  }
```

And then inherit it:

```
public class MyClass1 : Singleton<MyClass1>
{
}
```